# ReactJS - Handling onClick events for an entire section except for a few child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

This has been asked a few times with regards to using just normal JavaScript or jQuery, which I've successfully accomplished (in the BatmanJS framework). I'm rewriting my app with React and I'm having an issue accomplishing this.

So I have a parent div, with many child elements of various nested elements inside those. I basically want the entire parent div and every child element to handle a click event, except when a few of the child elements are clicked; I want those to trigger another event.

Normally I would do this:

```
$(parentDiv).on('click',
  '.subParent *:not(a):not(button):not(.ignore-click)',
  handleClick);
```

That basically watches for the click on all child elements except any with the class `.ignore-click`. This worked fine outside of React.

In React, I did this:

```
$(this.getDOMNode()).on('click',
  '.subParent *:not(a):not(button):not(.ignore-click)',
  this.handleClick);
```

And I can't get it to work properly no matter what I try. The CSS selector in the query works fine. For example, it doesn't trigger for any buttons, but will still trigger for the parent div surrounding the button, which I want, but not when the actual button is clicked.

I'm using `e.stopPropagation` in the handler.

If there's a better way to solve this without jQuery, I'd be up for that as well. I even thought about adding `onClick=""` to every element except the ones I wanted, but I would still run into the issue where a parent had the event and would still trigger.

Here's my component code:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(this.getDOMNode()).on('click','.subParent *:not(a):not(button):not(.ignore-click)',this.handleClick);
    },
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var el = e.currentTarget;
        console.log('event1: ' + el);
    },
    handleButtonClick: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('event2: ' + e.currentTarget);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="parentDiv">
                <div className="subParent">
                    <div className="anotherDiv">
                        <p>Some text</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="anotherDiv">
                        <button className="ignore-click" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Trigger event2</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rissk13/q29qo84a/).

Comment: Why not just have a react click handler on the parent element and then check the target of the click is one you want to respond to in that handler via e.target. Then simply do nothing if it's not a child element you want to respond to clicks on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the event handler that you want each component to use (pass by setting it as a prop in the parent call to it). For example:

```
var React = require('react');

var Parent = React.createClass({
  onClickA: function(e) {
    // do stuff
  },
  onClickB: function(e) {
    // do stuff
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildA onClick={this.onClickA} />
        <ChildB onClick={this.onClickB} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Ideally with React, you are never changing the DOM, and if you do need to select from the DOM, you should use the React methods to do so ([React.findDOMNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html));

Comment: I understand the React DOM methods (I used this.getDOMNode() in my example). I was just trying to prevent having to add a ton of onClicks (in my case, 13). But I did, and it does work. I guess it's not horrible, and it is explicit which helps readability, I guess I was just looking for a simple one-liner similar to the jQuery line I used. But I know React is different, so this may just be the solution. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) . I think that might be what you are looking for in terms of style and simplicity. Using that, each component would have its own store type, and the onClick would be written once in the store, and each component of that type would connect to its proper store and get the onClick from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm actually using React with Meteor for my data handling. And this event is to manipulate the DOM (slideToggle a div). For now I'll probably stick to putting the onClick on every element I want it on, since it works, and refactor it in the future if needed. What would be nice is if I could figure out how to make a <SlideToggle/> component that handles this.